# Проблемы с чтением файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы

У меня есть задание прочитать файл и прогнать по этой функции, сама функция работает корректно. Хотя когда ей передают значение из прочитанного файла то она говорит что нету индекса 0. Но если отправить ей точную копию строки из файла то проблем не будет.

```
def do(x):
    x= str(x)
    S = ''
    while True:
        c = 2
        a = x[0]
        while x[1:c].isdigit():
            c +=1
            if c-2 == len(x)-1:
                break
        b =x[1:c-1] 
        S += a * int(b)
        x = x[c-1:]
        if x == '':
            break
    print(S) 
do('r9V20v9m4v17q1X18H5a14r6t8D12o18L2q19C20w2D20l16C17b8J20v6p1L19y4') #в файле находиться тоже самое
with open('do.txt') as inf:
    for i in inf:
        i = inf.readline()
        do(i)
```

Выдаёт это:

```
rrrrrrrrrVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVvvvvvvvvvmmmmvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvqXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXHHHHHaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrttttttttDDDDDDDDDDDDooooooooooooooooooLLqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCwwDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDllllllllllllllllCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCbbbbbbbbJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJvvvvvvpLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLyyyy

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Programs\Study\Script.py", line 21, in <module>
        do(i)
      File "C:\Programs\Study\Script.py", line 6, in do
        a = x[0]
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: добавь print(i) перед do(i) и посмотри, что у тебя там находится. Учись элементарным методам отладки и поиска ошибок.

Comment: Ничего не выводит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in inf:
    i = inf.readline()
```

В этом коде вы **два раза** пытаетесь прочитать строку из файла, и во второй раз у вас ничего не читается, потому что всё уже прочитано ещё в первый раз.

Вот эта строка кода читает строку из файла и помещает её в переменную `i`:

```
for i in inf:
```

После чего вот эта строка пытается прочитать из файла ещё одну строку, а файл уже кончился, строк в нём больше нет и не прочитывается уже ничего:

```
    i = inf.readline()
```

Оставьте только какой-то один метод чтения из файла и всё заработает. Например, так, если у вас в файле только одна строка:

```
with open('do.txt') as inf:
    i = inf.readline()
    do(i)
```

Или так, если строк много и каждую нужно отдельно обработать вашей функцией:

```
with open('do.txt') as inf:
    for i in inf:
        do(i)
```

Comment: так читается только первая строка. Лучше оставить цикл `for`, а `inf.readline` убрать

Comment: @Danis В общем случае да. Но в данном случае речь шла о том, что в файле вроде всего одна строка. Ну, дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо помогло